# Vector field that vanishes in a non empty open set of $S^2$.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, spheres

I have to find a non-trivial vector field $V$ on the emty sphere $S^2$ which vaishes in a non-empty open set of $S^2$.
I tried something as $V(x,y,z)=0$ if $z<0$ and $V(x,y,z)=(\text{something that has length }z)$ otherwise. In this way $V$ is continuos but it is not of class $C^\infty$.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use bump functions.

Comment: Expanding on the above comment: cover $S^2$ with two charts, and choose a bump function with support in the domain of one chart. Cook the ingredients for 5 minutes and serve hot.

Comment: I presume you are not requiring the set of points where $V$ vanishes to be open (because that is not possible), but rather that you want $V$ to vanish on a set that contains an open set. You can use bump functions to get such a $V$ or you can modifya  vector field on the northern hemisphere corresponding to a rotation around the polar axis so that it becomes 0 on the equator and then extend it to 0 o n the southern hemisphere.